# Why does methodvistor.visitMaxs(0,0) crash in Java asm?

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I am using Java ASM (4.0) to write a simple compiler. I use the classWriter(COMPUTE_FRAMES) to write a class.

It all works well with simple programs, but when I start to nest jumps (e.g. a while statement in an IfThenElse statement) and after that I call methodVisitor.visitMaxs(0,0) it gives me the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.objectweb.asm.Frame.a(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter.visitMaxs(Unknown Source)
at front.ir.visitors.ClassWriterVisitor.visitAstProcedure(ClassWriterVisitor.java:182)
at front.ir.visitors.ClassWriterVisitor.visitAstProcedure(ClassWriterVisitor.java:1)
at front.ir.ASTProcedure.accept(ASTProcedure.java:27)
at front.ir.visitors.ClassWriterVisitor.visitProgram(ClassWriterVisitor.java:235)
at front.ir.visitors.ClassWriterVisitor.visitProgram(ClassWriterVisitor.java:1)
at front.ir.ASTProgram.accept(ASTProgram.java:37)
at front.FrontEnd.main(FrontEnd.java:122)
```

The code for my while statements:

```
    jumplabels.push(new Label());

    L2 = new Label();

    mv.visitJumpInsn(Opcodes.GOTO, L2);
    mv.visitLabel(jumplabels.peek());
    whi.stmt.accept(this);
    mv.visitLabel(L2);
    whi.condition.accept(this);
    jumplabels.pop();
```

And my IfThenElse :

```
    jumplabels.push(new Label());

    L2 = new Label();
    L1 = new Label();

    ifthenelse.condition.accept(this);
    mv.visitJumpInsn(Opcodes.GOTO, L2);
    mv.visitLabel(jumplabels.peek());
    ifthenelse.thenStmt.accept(this);
    mv.visitJumpInsn(Opcodes.GOTO, L1);
    mv.visitLabel(L2);
    if (ifthenelse.elseStmt != null) {
        ifthenelse.elseStmt.accept(this);
    }       
    mv.visitLabel(L1);

    jumplabels.pop();
```

The condition.accept(this) will insert the right condition and jump to the last label pushed on the stack (e.g. IFEQ jumplabels.peek()).

I hope anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong. And sorry for the perhaps unclear code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rethink the way you are compiling these statements. If statement usually don't have two `GOTO` instructions. Also, you should get rid of the `jumplabels` stack. In my compiler, this is the way I compile an `if` statement:

```
org.objectweb.asm.Label elseEnd = new org.objectweb.asm.Label();
// Condition
this.condition.writeInvJump(writer, elseStart);
this.then.writeStatement(writer);
writer.writeJumpInsn(Opcodes.GOTO, elseEnd);
writer.writeFrameLabel(elseStart);
this.elseThen.writeStatement(writer);
writer.writeFrameLabel(elseEnd);
```

`writeStatement` simply writes the AST node (this chunk of code is itself in `writeStatement`). `writeInvJump` writes a jump instruction that jumps to the specified label if the expression evaluates to false. Both are members and implemented in all subtypes of `IValue`. (Note that I am using a custom `MethodWriter` that delegates calls to an ASM `MethodWriter` and uses a slightly different naming format)

([IfStatement Source](https://github.com/Clashsoft/Dyvil/blob/master/src/compiler/dyvil/tools/compiler/ast/statement/IfStatement.java#L293)) ([IValue Source](https://github.com/Clashsoft/Dyvil/blob/master/src/compiler/dyvil/tools/compiler/ast/value/IValue.java#L188))

---

For the sake of completeness, here is the code for `WhileStatement.writeStatement`:

```
writer.writeFrameLabel(this.startLabel.target);
this.condition.writeInvJump(writer, this.endLabel.target);
this.action.writeStatement(writer);
writer.writeJumpInsn(Opcodes.GOTO, this.startLabel.target);

writer.writeFrameLabel(this.endLabel.target);
```

([WhileStatement Source](https://github.com/Clashsoft/Dyvil/blob/master/src/compiler/dyvil/tools/compiler/ast/statement/WhileStatement.java#L227))

Comment: Thank you so much! My method was way to sloppy indeed. Now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know exactly what you are doing wrong, but this crash at this point always indicates that the bytecode you have written is incorrect in some way. When we hit this, we run it again with a debug switch enabled, where the debug switch triggers a call on CheckClassAdapter.verify(), which produces a listing of the bytecode which, with practice, you can interpret to work out where you went wrong.

In response to your question, here is some more detail of what we do.

We actually have two options we can set, called `displayByteCode` and `debugByteCode`. The display option prints the bytecode to a file unconditionally, the debug option only swings into action if something goes wrong.

First, we create a `ClassWriter cw`, which we use to create the class. If the `displayByteCode` option is on, then we immediately wrap this in a `TraceClassVisitor`, giving it a `PrintWriter` to which the generated bytecode is written.

On completion (after calling `cw.visitEnd()`), if the `debugByteCode` option is on, we do the following:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
CheckClassAdapter.verify(new ClassReader(cw.toByteArray()), false, new PrintWriter(sw));
if (sw.toString().length() != 0) {
    System.err.println("Verify Output for " + objectName + ":");
    try {
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("ByteCodeOutput.txt"));
                    out.write(sw.toString());
                    out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception " + e);
    }
    System.err.println(sw);
    throw new IllegalStateException("Bytecode failed verification");
}
```

This code can almost certainly be improved, but since it's only needed in emergencies, it's good enough for our purposes.

Comment: Hi, could you please shed more light on this? I am very keen to know how to debug this, or at least be able to see the bytecode.

Comment: I've added more info.